# How to use correct syntax in javascript-events variables in a HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, var

In my script, I am using this code to get an image:

```
var image ="<img src='/uploads/carImage.png' alt='image in infowindow'>"
```

This works perfectly well and the `carImage` is displayed, but what I want to do, is to exchange `carImage` with a variable like:

```
var myImage = "carImage.png"
var image ="<img src='/uploads/myImage' alt='image in infowindow'>"
```

I understand, I need a specific syntax for *myImage*, but I am not able to find it.
So my question is: What is the correct syntax for the variable *myImage* inside the variable *image*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var image ="<img src='/uploads/" + myImage + "' alt='image in infowindow'>"
```